# Using "sudo openconnect" sets VPN DNS, but Gnome VPN setups don't on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

OK, forgive me, but this is my first time posting about openconnect issues. Before my disk crash, I was using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I reinstalled it and remembered that to make it connect to my GlobalProtect work VPN, I had to download and rebuild openconnect 8. Yeech... I checked and found that 20.04 includes openconnect 8... Yes!

I tested and was able to initiate a full VPN connection over the command line. I have to sudo to make it work, but that works... However, I wanted to do this from the GUI, and this is where things fall over.

Through some Google-Fu, I found that I had to install a number of network-manager packages to make the GUI work. So, I installed these packages:

```
network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1 all [installed]
network-manager-gnome/focal,now 1.8.24-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-openconnect-gnome/focal,now 1.2.6-1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-openconnect/focal,now 1.2.6-1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-openvpn-gnome/focal,now 1.8.12-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
network-manager-openvpn/focal,now 1.8.12-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
network-manager-pptp-gnome/focal,now 1.2.8-2 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-pptp/focal,now 1.2.8-2 amd64 [installed]
network-manager/focal-updates,now 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Now, I can create a VPN entry using the standard VPN dialogs, and the VPN connects. But does not set DNS *at all* for the VPN connections. Even if the VPN settings specifically state DNS servers to use.

I'm sure that this is PEBKAC, and that I either don't have something installed or I missed a configuration step.

My VPN connection settings:

```
[connection]
id=My VPN
uuid=f4ff9996-9079-4c8e-bbce-fda376ec4bb2
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=
timestamp=1595512597

[vpn]
authtype=password
autoconnect-flags=0
certsigs-flags=0
cookie-flags=2
enable_csd_trojan=no
gateway=redacted-hostname
gateway-flags=2
gwcert-flags=2
lasthost-flags=0
pem_passphrase_fsid=no
prevent_invalid_cert=no
protocol=gp
reported_os=Linux
stoken_source=disabled
xmlconfig-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect

[vpn-secrets]
lasthost=ravpn-njdc.hcl.com

[ipv4]
dns=10.10.10.10;10.10.11.11;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
never-default=true

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

One thing I noticed was that `sudo openconnect` essentially creates a "tun0" interface and sets it up, and the GUI VPN setup uses "vpn0", "vpn1" and such (one interface per VPN).

When I connect via `sudo openconnect` the DNS settings get added to `resolvectl status` output, when I use the GUI, DNS settings don't get added to the specified "vpnX" interface. Any ideas why? Or what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? :)

Comment: @ChaimEliyah No, but the symptoms are different now...  It doesn't show in resolvectl status... Instead openconnect run as root modifies the resolv.conf file... While the GUI VPN connection still leaves me unable to look up internal hosts...

Comment: Ah, got it. Yeah I had trouble with DNS on one network as well, still can't get on to the other.

Comment: Is it possible to change interface names from "vpn0", "vpn1".. to "tun0", "tun1"? I had the similar problem with wrapping openconnect as service until I renamed "openconnect0" to "tun0".